# XML Schema site is not exists.. (when unmarshalling xml)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I want to try a test about unmarshalling by xml.
So I writing codes which are in a book.
Codes are like this..

sqlmap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sqlmap xmlns="http://www.example.org/sqlmap/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/sqlmap/ http://www.example.org/sqlmap/sqlmap.xsd">

<sql key="add">insert</sql>
<sql key="get">select</sql>
<sql key="delete">delete</sql>
</sqlmap>
```

JaxbTest.java

```
package springbook.learningtest.jdk.jaxb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;



import org.junit.Test;

import springbook.user.sqlservice.jaxb.SqlType;
import springbook.user.sqlservice.jaxb.Sqlmap;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class JaxbTest {
    @Test
    public void readSqlmap() throws JAXBException, IOException{
        String contextPath = Sqlmap.class.getPackage().getName();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        Sqlmap sqlmap = (Sqlmap) unmarshaller.unmarshal(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sqlmap.xml"));
        List<SqlType> sqlList = sqlmap.getSql();

        assertThat(sqlList.size(), is(3));
        assertThat(sqlList.get(0).getKey(), is("add"));
        assertThat(sqlList.get(0).getValue(), is("insert"));
        assertThat(sqlList.get(1).getKey(), is("get"));
        assertThat(sqlList.get(1).getValue(), is("select"));
        assertThat(sqlList.get(2).getKey(), is("delete"));
        assertThat(sqlList.get(2).getValue(), is("delete"));
    }
}
```

SqlMap.java

```
package springbook.user.sqlservice.jaxb;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;



@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "sql"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "sqlmap")
public class Sqlmap {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<SqlType> sql;


    public List<SqlType> getSql() {
        if (sql == null) {
            sql = new ArrayList<SqlType>();
        }
        return this.sql;
    }

}
```

SqlType.java

```
package springbook.user.sqlservice.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;



@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sqlType", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class SqlType {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "key", required = true)
    protected String key;


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public void setKey(String value) {
        this.key = value;
    }

}
```

But I faced with the problem because Namespace Site(http://example.org) is no more exists..
So compile is unavailable. Error code is like this..

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.example.org/sqlmap/", local:"sqlmap"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.org/sqlmap}sqlmap>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at springbook.learningtest.jdk.jaxb.JaxbTest.readSqlmap(JaxbTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I don't have knowledge about XML. I just want to compile it..
What I have to do?

Comment: Can you post the `Sqlmap` and `SqlType` classes?

Comment: I posted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements in the XML don't match their corresponding Java classes. Your XML declares them as belonging to the XML namespace

```
xmlns="http://www.example.org/sqlmap/"
```

but your classes say nothing of the sort.

You'll have to specify the namespace

```
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "sql" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "sqlmap", namespace = "http://www.example.org/sqlmap/")
public class Sqlmap {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.example.org/sqlmap/")
    private List<SqlType> sql;

    public List<SqlType> getSql() {
        return sql;
    }

    public void setSql(List<SqlType> sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }
}
```

for both the root and nested elements (they both belong to the namespace).

Comment: It goes well..! Thank you!

Comment: @velmont - Your error message indicated that you had mapped  namespace `http://www.example.org/sqlmap` it just didn't match the one in the XML document `http://www.example.org/sqlmap/` (extra slash).  This solution will work, but its easier if you just change the one line that in the `@XmlSchema` that's in the `package-info` class.  For more information on JAXB and namespaces:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: @velmont Yeah, Blaise is right. I had not noticed you already had namespace declared somewhere, but incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/sqlmap/ ../../../../../sqlmap.xsd ">
                                                  |                         |
                                                  |                         |
                                                  here                  and here
```

there are some space.

Answer (score 0):

An XML namespace is generally structured as a URL (it is not required to be), but it does not need to correspond to a real location.  [example.org](http://example.org/) is a domain that's reserved for illustrative purposes.

Your XML document has a `/` at the end of the namespace but your metadata does not.  You can fix this by changing your document to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sqlmap xmlns="http://www.example.org/sqlmap" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/sqlmap/ http://www.example.org/sqlmap/sqlmap.xsd">
    <sql key="add">insert</sql>
    <sql key="get">select</sql>
    <sql key="delete">delete</sql>
</sqlmap>
```

Or the namespace on the `@XmlSchema` on the `package-info` class.